# Как можно создать переменные из списка значений в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть некий список текстовых значений:
`a = ["lastName", "firstName", "middleName"]`
Как из него создать три переменные?

Вообще, из этого списка планирую тянуть имена столбцов в БД, а потом понадобятся и соответствующие переменные, но так как список может быть очень длинным, хотелось бы все это дело затолкать в цикл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как правильно отметил в своём ответе Сергей, динамически объявлять переменные в глобальной области видимости - плохая идея.

Но ведь совсем не обязательно объявлять их прямо в глобалке! Можно же создать для этих переменных отдельный объект (проще всего - словарь), а потом с ним и работать. Это очень удобно тем, что не загрязняет область видимости, и тем, что потом можно будет итерироваться по этому объекту.

```
a = ["lastName", "firstName", "middleName"]

my_vars = {}
my_vars.update( {k: None for k in a} )
print(my_vars)

        # программа выведет: {'middleName': None, 'firstName': None, 'lastName': None}
```

После этого вы можете обращаться к вашим переменным так:

```
my_dict['middleName']
```

Comment: dict.fromkeys(a)

Answer (score 2):

Динамически объявлять переменные это плохая идея. Но возможность есть:

```
for i in a:
    globals()[i] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class My:pass
for _ in 'aa', 'bb', 'cc': setattr(My, _, _)
print(My.bb, My.aa)
```